# How to add Text variable on GStreamer?

Tags: variables, text, overlay, gstreamer

I'm very new in GStreamer ? GStreamer is so great, I can overlay text, datetime on screen. Now I just wanna overlay a variable text like a random number or something else changing ?

Overlay a text:

```
gst-launch-1.0 imxv4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! 'video/x-raw,format=(string)NV12,width=1280,height=720,framerate=(fraction)30/1' ! textoverlay text="Hi StackOverflow" valignment=top halignment=left font-desc="Sans, 12" ! autovideosink
```

How can I do that ?

Thank you very much !

Toan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `text` variable is a property. You can set this via `g_object_set()` in the C api. You can use any other language where Glib/GStreamer bindings exist for. But note you need to write a real GStreamer application. You cannot does this by simply using `gst-lauch-1.0`. That application is good for testing purposes but only allows you to do that much within the GStreamer framework.

EDIT:

To the added code:

before:

```
 /* Wait until error or EOS */
  bus = gst_element_get_bus (pipeline);
```

try something like this:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    snprintf (var_str, sizeof(var_str), "%d",num++);
    g_object_set (text, "text", var_str, NULL);
    g_usleep(1000*1000);
  }
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! Do you have any example to refer ? I very exciting to hear from you !

Comment: Well, my GStreamer program don't have any loop. I mean how can I update value to overlay while gstreamer have no loop.

Comment: Even I added a loop in while from start of main to the end of program, It's still no effect. I just add a integer value and convert to string, each loop I plus i with 1. But in screen, value is still 1. Someone can explain for me ?

Comment: We don't see any code so what shall i suggest? Check the GStreamer samples if you are new to GStreamer and read the tutorials.

Comment: I watched GStreamer tutorials but I still can't solve it. This is my code, I forget to send it.

Comment: See EDIT in the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much. It's working perfectly. I won't do this without your help !

Comment: May you see this issue ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60772967/how-to-close-gstreamer-application-automatic